# Migrating Background processing to Hangfire

Tags: c#, .net, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles, hangfire

I have a web application which consist of 1 web role and 1 worker role instance. The webrole basically aggregates some blobs on blob storage and the worker comes and sweeps the stored files and processes them.

The problem is if I were to use 2 worker role instances, there may be some duplicate results due to the fact that the blobs only get removed on successful processing. In order to avoid this I decided to use Hangfire.

What I plan on doing is, when the web role gets the request, not only it will save the file to blob storage but also enqueue the processing task for that file. Then Hangfire worker threads will process it.

This raises another question: where should I deploy hangfire?

If I deploy hangfire onto web role instances, I will be able to access the UI since it has IIS, but I won't be able to isolate the resources used for background processing from the web role itself. If I deploy it onto worker role instances, it won't be able to serve the UI, since there's no IIS.

Is there a way to have web role instance fire the tasks but have the worker instance look for and consume them? If so, how?